# Double cannot be dereferenced?

Tags: java, double

```
String mins = minsField.getText(); 

    int Mins;
    try
    {
        Mins = Integer.parseInt(mins);

     }
     catch (NumberFormatException e)
     {
         Mins = 0;
     }

    double hours = Mins / 60;

    hours.setText(hoursminsfield);
```

The problem is that `Double cannot be dereferenced`.

Comment: @Daniel, I fail to see how the accepted answer relates to your question at all. You should have asked _another_ question when you fixed the original problem.

Comment: If you want to use hours as double, you have to leave int-arithmetic, which is used, if you mix an int with an literal int like 60: `double hours = Mins / 60;` Use a literal double like 60.0 instead.

Comment: Please don't use capital letter for variable `int Mins;` change it into `int minutes` or `int mints`. The other programmers will be misunderstand with that, they will think `Mins` is a class not a variable. Please read this [Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## EDIT  4/23/12

`double cannot be dereferenced` is the error some Java compilers give when you try to call a method on a primitive.  It seems to me `double has no such method` would be more helpful, but what do I know.

From your code, it seems you think you can copy a text representation of `hours` into `hoursminfield` by doing
    hours.setText(hoursminfield);
This has a few errors:
1) hours is a `double` which is a primitive type, there are NO methods you can call on it.  This is what gives you the error you asked about.
2) you don't say what type hoursminfield is, maybe you haven't even declared it yet.
3) it is unusual to set the value of a variable by having it be the argument to a method.  It happens sometimes, but not usually.

The lines of code that do what you seem to want are:

```
String hoursrminfield; // you better declare any variable you are using

// wrap hours in a Double, then use toString() on that Double
hoursminfield = Double.valueOf(hours).toString(); 

// or else a different way to wrap in a double using the Double constructor:
(new Double(hours)).toString(); 

// or else use the very helpful valueOf() method from the class String which will 
// create a string version of any primitive type:
hoursminfield = String.valueOf(hours);
```

## ORIGINAL ANSWER (addressed a different problem in your code):

In `double hours = Mins / 60;` you are dividing two `int`s.  You will get the `int` value of that division, so if 
    Mins = 43;
    double hours = Mins / 60;
    // Mins / 60 is an int = 0.  assigning it to double hours makes
    // hours a double equal to zero.

What you need to do is:

```
double hours = Mins / ((double) 60);
```

or something like that, you need to cast some part of your division to a `double` in order to force the division to be done with `double`s and not `int`s.

Comment: I am puttin up another problem i am having if you would be so awesome to give me some advice on aswell, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is great, an accepted answer that is correct, and I'm getting downvoted!  Maybe one of you power users downvoting could tell me why.

Comment: @mwengler It actually doesn't answer the question. The question was about what was causing the error `Double cannot be dereferenced`. The fact that your answer was accepted is inconsequential (and actually just draws more attention to the fact that it is incorrect).

Comment: @Zshazz I guess the experts would know better who answered his question than questioner would.  I'll know to edit the question next time before answering what the questioner really meant.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't specified the language but, if it's Java, there's a big difference between the basic type `double` and the class `Double`.

In any case, your `setText` seems the wrong way around. The `setText` method would belong to the data *field,* not the data you're trying to put in there:

```
hoursminsfield.setText (hours);
```

In other words, you want to set the text of the field, using the double you just calculated. Whether you can pass a double is a different matter which *may* need to be examined.

Another thing:

```
double hours = Mins / 60;
```

will, if `Mins` is an integer`, give you an *integer* value which you then put into a double. That means it will be truncated. If you want to ensure you keep precision following the division, you can use something like:

```
double hours = (double) Mins / 60.0;
```

(though it may work with only one of those changes, I prefer to make all terms explicit).

Comment: Yeah its java my bad, but can you tell me how i can fix this? please? lol

Comment: Uhm, they did.  you can't call `setText` on a Double because a Double is just a number.  It doesn't have a `setText` method because it doesn't have any text...

Comment: ahh ok i get ya, can you suggest what i can do then? cause im pretty new at this and have nearly no idea what to do

Comment: @Daniel, examine my code snippet _very_ carefully. I've swapped over `hourminsfield` and `hours` from what you had. That's your first step.

Comment: i inserted Double.toString(hours), was that right to do? :S cause now it doesnt really give me the right answer, like if i put in 240 mins it give me 4 hours but if i put in 256 mins it still gives me 4 hours

Comment: Try changing your assignment to something like `double hours = (double) Mins / 60.0;`. When you divide an integer by 60, you get an integer, not matter _where_ you eventually put the result.

Comment: I am puttin up another problem i am having if you would be so awesome to give me some advice on aswell, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Daniel, SO is not a message board. If you have a different problem, ask a different question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this way

```
double hours = Mins / 60.0
```

I always use the above statement to get the double value