# Double cannot be dereferenced...?

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Comparator;
public class RectangleComparator implements Comparator
{
      public int compare(Object object1, Object object2)
      {
        Rectangle rec1 = (Rectangle) object1;
        Rectangle rec2 = (Rectangle) object2;

        return rec1.getWidth().compareTo(rec2.getWidth());
    }
}
```

For some reason, I'm getting the error double cannot be dereferenced. Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: BTW, it's rarely a good idea to compare float/double values for exact equality. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915462/how-should-i-do-floating-point-comparison

Answer (score 4, accepted):

rocketboy is correct with regard to why this is happening.

Consider using the Double wrapper class like this

```
new Double(rec1.getWidth()).compareTo(rec2.getWidth());
```

Only the first value need to be converted to a wrapper Double, the second one will be auto boxed.

Comment: You should not use `new Double(…)` at all. Please get into the habit of using `Double.valueOf(…)` as this will allow Java to reuse existing objects. Of course that’s even more important for small integers or longs.

Comment: @MichaelPiefel Does this depend on the implementation or am I missing something? The `Double.valueOf(double d)` seem to be just calling new `Double(double d)` under the wraps.

Comment: That’s correct (for my Oracle JDK) – but it just _might_ be better, as the comment there suggests. It’s actually implemented for integers and longs between -128 and 127. I wonder if there really is an implementation that caches more and whether that is actually more efficient in any way.

Comment: I checked in the openjdk 1.6 and 1.7. There's no way caching is implemented at their current state.

Answer (score 5):

To compare two `double` primitives:

Java old school:

```
return new Double(rec1.getWidth()).compareTo(new Double(rec2.getWidth());
```

Java 1.4 onwards:

```
return Double.compare(rec1.getWidth(), rec2.getWidth());
```

Comment: +1 for adding the newer Java7 version which is much more efficient that creating Double wrappers.

Comment: Can you explain or link as to why this is different?

Comment: While the second one is much cleaner and preferable is it really more efficient?

Comment: @Thihara The first one creates two new Double objects.  The second does math on the double values directly.  I'm confused where the Java 7 part comes in, though, as the javadocs seem to say  Double.compare(double, double) has been around since 1.4

Comment: @Bohemian, What is so wrong in converting a value to string and comparing them for equality? My answer was voted down but I found another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10274108/295264) suggesting the same thing on his last option.

Comment: @Starx We aren't (just) comparing equality here - it's a comparator. You're defining an ordering.  Converting to a string changes the ordering from the natural ordering of doubles to a string based ordering (e.g. 100 comes before 11)

Comment: The "Java 7" version has been around since Java 1.4.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't know why I thought that. Thanks for commenting (answer corrected)

Comment: Yeah... I thought it has been around.

Answer (score 3):

I think your `Rectangle.getWidth()` returns a `double`. It is not a wrapper Object like Double, so the dot operator cannot be used.

Had it been:
`Double getWidth()` instead of `double getWidth()`

then `rec1.getWidth().compareTo(rec2.getWidth());` would have been valid.

[How to compare doubles in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081827/how-to-compare-two-double-values-in-java)