# Javascript to java code not working

Tags: javascript, java

Hi so i am trying to convert this JavaScript code to Java i can't seem to be able to do it that good am stuck in the last part i need to convert my JavaScript code to java the encrypt part.

JavaScript Code:

```
Encrypt = function (strIn) {
    var strOut = String();
    var lenIn = strIn.length;
    var i = 0;
    var numRand;
    while (i < lenIn) {
        numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 66) + 36;
        strOut += (strIn.charCodeAt(i) + numRand).toString(27) + numRand.toString(27);
        i++;
    }
    return strOut;
};
```

Java Code:

```
public static String Encrypt(String strIn) {

    String strOut = null;
    int lenIn = strIn.length();
    int i = 0;

    double numRand;

    while (i < lenIn) {
        numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 66) + 36;
        strOut += (strIn.charAt(i) + numRand).toString(27) + numRand.toString(27);
        i++;
    }
    return strOut;
}
```

Am having an error in this line of code:

```
strOut += (strIn.charAt(i) + numRand).toString(27) + numRand.toString(27);
```

The Error:

```
Error:(22, 50) java: double cannot be dereferenced
```

I can't seem to be able to tell why any help is wonderful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273949/double-cannot-be-dereferenced can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are running into that `double` is a primitive type (along with `char` and `int`) and so it doesn't have a `toString()` method (which in Java belongs to `Object`). To dig deeper, the reason your error message complains about a `double` is because your `numRand` variable is of type double, and so due to casting `strIn.charAt(i) + numRand` also becomes a double.

Instead you can use something like `Integer.toString(value, radix)`, which is a static member of `Integer`. The revised code might look like...

```
strOut += Integer.toString((int)(strIn.charAt(i) + (char)numRand), 27) + 
          Integer.toString((int)numRand, 27);
```

Comment: In addition, I'd initialize `String strOut = ""` and not to `null`. Also change `Encrypt` as `encrypt` to follow Java naming conventions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer works perfectly now i know what to use next time i do anything like this :).