# Java, Sort Array of doubles and its indexes

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have read a lot about this in this forum and other fora, but i still cannot get a concrete answer. Anyway i decided to do it like this:

Here is a class to hold a string and an integer:

```
public class Tuple{

    private String token;
    private int docID;



    public Tuple(String token, int docID) {
        this.token = token;
        this.docID = docID;
    }

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    public int getDocID() {
        return docID;
    }
    public void setDocID(int docID) {
        this.docID = docID;
    }

}
```

And then, i create an array-list to put these tuples `private ArrayList<Tuple> temps = new ArrayList<>();`

Then i populate the arraylist like this:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < numberOfDocs; i++ )
{
    Tuple cat = new Tuple(Double.toString(vect[i]),i);
    temps.add(cat);
}
```

Eventually, I am sorting the array like this:

```
public void sortTmp() 
{
    Collections.sort(temps, new Comparator<Tuple>() 
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Tuple tr2, Tuple tr1)
        {
            return tr2.getToken().compareTo(tr1.getToken());
        }
    });
}
```

There is some problem with java and doubles and i cannot use directly my double matrix so i have to do `Double.toString()` . The results are sorted, but not entirely correct because string calculation from double is not very accurate in terms of double number sorting.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorting Lexically is probably not what you want. Why can't you use Doubles? Or better: what makes you think you can't? "There is some problem with java and doubles" - mostly it's the developers who have problems with doubles rather than java.

Comment: @Fildor this particular line `return  tr2.getToken().compareTo(tr1.getToken());` is wrong when i change everything from `string` type to `double` type. According to my IDE: `double cannot be dereferenced`

Comment: Yes, then change *that* line so it works for double. You can use the Double wrapper if you need to use compareTo.

Comment: Yuo should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10274108/4391450) explaining that call a method on a primitive give that problem. Using a wrapper should solve it

Comment: For example do `return Double.compare( tr2.getToken(), tr1.getToken() );` (when changing so that getToken() returns `double`)

Comment: @Fildor will try it now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are comparing `double`s lexicographically, by their `String` representation, you might indeed find some unexpected results.

You could either:

- refactor `Tuple` so that `token` is a `double` (or wrapper `Double` if you want to invoke `compareTo` on the instance)
- otherwise, in your `Comparator`, you can invoke `Double.parseDouble` on your `String`s (which should be relatively safe since the `String`s come from `double`s in the first place), and invoke `compareTo` on the returned `Double` wrapper.

The last option sounds quite ugly because you have a bunch of seemingly unnecessary back-and-forth conversions between `Double` and `String` and vice-versa.

It would also imply a performance degradation, since `compareTo` will be invoked multiple times when sorting your collection.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  What do you mean by wrapper `Double`? I tried to change my `Tuple` class; where `string`, i put `double`, but in line `return tr2.getToken().compareTo(tr1.getToken());` i am getting `double cannot be dereferenced` error.

Comment: @Javac `Double` != `double` the latter is primitive. You cannot call functions on it like you are trying to. `Double` is a wrapper for that primitive type to allow exactly this (amongst other purposes). Going form `double` to its corresponding `Double` is referred to as "boxing".

Comment: @Javac if you want to use primitives, you can invoke static `Double.compare(double d1, double d2)` instead of invoking `compareTo`. Otherwise you can refactor with `Double` wrappers as I was saying and Fildor pointed out too.

Comment: I am accepting this one. It was the `Double`. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can store token as double in your `Tuple`  and implements `Comparable` interface. in `getToken` you can return string presentation of double in form which you are actually needed.

```
public class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple>{

    private double token;
    private int docID;

    public Tuple(double token, int docID) {
        this.token = token;
        this.docID = docID;

    }

    public String getToken() {
        return String.valueOf(token);
    }
    public void setToken(double token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    public int getDocID() {
        return docID;
    }
    public void setDocID(int docID) {
        this.docID = docID;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tuple o) {
        return Double.compare(this.token, o.token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to convert doubles into strings, it's safer to use

```
BigDecimal.valueOf(vect[i])).toString();
```

since it handles double unpredictability.

Comment: Well, he shouldn't do that at all. Sorting Lexicographically on doubles will surely introduce surprises. Just think of values that will be represented in Mathematical notation ...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same idea as Vlad Bochenin:

You just implement `Comparable` and override `compareTo`:

```
public class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple> {

    public Double token;
    public int docID;

    public Tuple(final double token, final int docID) {
        this.token = token;
        this.docID = docID;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final Tuple o) {
        return this.token.compareTo(o.token);
    }
}
```

And a unit test:

```
public class TestTuple {

    @Test
    public void testSort() {
        final Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        final int numberOfDocs = 100;
        final ArrayList<Tuple> temp = new ArrayList<Tuple>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDocs; i++) {
            temp.add(new Tuple(r.nextDouble(), i));
        }
        Collections.sort(temp);

        Tuple old = temp.get(0);
        // test if sorted
        for (final Tuple next : temp) {
            Assert.assertTrue(next.token >= old.token);
            old = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can store token as double in your Tuple and implements Comparable interface. in getToken you can return string presentation of double in form which you are actually needed.

```
private double token;
private int docID;

public Tuple(double token, int docID) {
    this.token = token;
    this.docID = docID;

}

public String getToken() {
    return String.valueOf(token);
}
public void setToken(double token) {
    this.token = token;
}
public int getDocID() {
    return docID;
}
public void setDocID(int docID) {
    this.docID = docID;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Tuple o) {
    return Double.compare(this.token, o.token);
}
```

}

[To see More about CompareTo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm)

Comment: this is all copy of my answer (and my poor English ), without any reference on it. Is it kind of joke?

Comment: If you want to add the link to Vlad's answer, use a comment. Don't copy his answer.