# double cannot be converted to Calculator incompatible types

Tags: java

I just made this account, and I also just started programming java a few days ago just out of interest. I've been having an extremely hard time writing a Calculator program using objects and methods instead of if/then statements.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Calculator {
    double x;
    double y;
    double result;

public Calculator(double a, double b) {
    x = a;
    y = b;
}


public double Add(double numOne, double numTwo) {
    x = numOne;
    y = numTwo;
    result = x + y;
    return result;
}

public double Subtract(double numOne, double numTwo) {
    x = numOne;
    y = numTwo;
    result = x - y;
    return result;
}

public double Multiply(double numOne, double numTwo) {
    x = numOne;
    y = numTwo;
    result = x * y;
    return result;
}

public double Divide(double numOne, double numTwo) {
    x = numOne;
    y = numTwo;
    result = x / y;
    return result;
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("First number: ");
    Double firstNum = input.nextDouble();
    
    input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Operator: ");
    String operator = input.nextLine();
    
    System.out.println("Last number: ");
    Double secNum = input.nextDouble();
    
    if(operator == "+") {
        Calculator ans = new Calculator(firstNum, secNum);
        ans = ans.Add(firstNum, secNum);
        
    }

}
```

}

I cannot figure out how to work around how this code uses doubles, as when calling the class I get "double cannot be converted" when I'm not trying to convert any doubles besides the ones declared in the class. I know this isn't a conventional way of making a calculator I just wanted to improve my knowledge of methods and classes. Thanks!

The error is on line 59, error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Calculator

Comment: What are the two parameters in the constructor of `Calculator` for?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assing double to `Calculator` instance, which is not possible.

See last line:

`ans = ans.Add(firstNum, secNum);`.

Method `Add` returns double and you are trying to assing it to `Calculator` reference.

What you can do:

1. Assing returned double to double reference.

   `double result = ans.Add(firstNum, secNum);`

Comment: that was my original code but then I get the error "double cannot be dereferenced" when I change it to that

Comment: @quidaaya You probably did not do that, because that code work. See this Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273949/double-cannot-be-dereferenced/10274108

Answer (score 0):

Also, you don't need to copy the parameters in your methods :

```
public double Add(double numOne, double numTwo) {
   x = numOne;
   y = numTwo;
   result = x + y;
   return result;
}
```

Could be simplified to :

```
public double Add(double numOne, double numTwo) {
   return numOne + numTwo;
}
```

Because you don't use the fields `x` and `y` later in your class.